# Как считать данные из JSON и записать в переменную

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс Valera и метод init для инициализации его полей. Как можно считать данные из JSON объекта и записать их в переменные?

```
public class Valera
{
    private int health; // Здоровье 0-100
    private int mana; // Мана 0-100
    private int happiness; // Жизнерадостность (-10; 10)
    private int fatigue; // Усталость 0-100
    private bool dead; // Состояние Валеры

    Valera init() 
    {
        
        return this;
    }
}
```

JSON объект:

```
{
  "health" : "100",
  "mana": "50",
  "happiness": "0",
  "fatigue": "50",
  "dead": "false"
}
```

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Text.Json;

var jsonObject = "{ \"health\": 100, \"mana\": 50, \"happiness\": 0, \"fatigue\": 50, \"dead\": false }";

var valera = Valera.Init(jsonObject);

Console.WriteLine(valera);

public class Valera
{
    public int health { get; set; } // Здоровье 0-100
    public int mana { get; set; } // Мана 0-100
    public int happiness { get; set; } // Жизнерадостность (-10; 10)
    public int fatigue { get; set; } // Усталость 0-100
    public bool dead { get; set; } // Состояние Валеры

    public static Valera Init(string json) => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Valera>(json);

    public override string ToString() => $"Valera have {health} hp";
}
```